# Does LLC payment count as payment to me (for unemployment purposes)

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, covid-19, unemployment

In the summer I received unemployment payments from California thanks to new federal laws that gave benefits to self employed business owners. The specific TYPE of unemployment for self-employed people, as for the new laws, is called PUA (Pandemic Unemployment Assistance).

I will likely restart the program in now in 2021.

I have created a single member LLC (I’m the only member/owner), and it seems like more grey area. If the LLC is paid, but the money doesn’t move from the LLC account to my personal account, does that count as payment to me for the purposes of received EDD?

This is important since if it’s considered payment to me, then I can’t receive EDD when that payment came. If it’s not considered payment to me, however, I can still receive EDD.

Comment: What kind of payment was it? Was it payment for work done? Was it bond interest?

Comment: For most purposes, a payment to a single-member LLC is the same as a payment to the person.